# What does i += x > 0 mean?

Tags: python

I'm reviewing a block of code and I wonder what this expression means:

```
target += counter[s[left]] >= 0
```

Comment: You add 1 if the condition is true, and 0 if false

Comment: ` target += counter[s[left]] >= 0` means ` target += (counter[s[left]] >= 0)` where `counter[s[left]] >= 0` is a `Boolean` which evaluates either to `True` or `False` based on condition

Comment: @azro what if s[left] doesn't exist in counter[]?

Comment: Hint: `int(True)` is 1. But don't do weird things, everyone will hate you.

Comment: It'll raise an error,

Comment: This is a classical case of not following the Zen of Python, in particular the line "Readability counts.".

Comment: are you asking about the in-place operation `+=` ?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, ah... that's not clear from azro's second comment, which looks like a snarky response to the question without a mention or quotation in it. I'll remove my comments.

Comment: @Tomerikoo it will raise the error if `s` is a list, tuple, or dict, which could be prevented by using a `defaultdict` if needed

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order
You can run the code with some "samples" and see what happends.

Answer (score 7):

`counter[s[left]] >= 0` evaluates to a boolean, that is `True` or `False`.

Putting that aside,  `target += val` is equivallent to `target = target + val`.

Since `bool` subclasses `int`, in a mathematical context `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

In essence, this line (presumably inside a loop that modifies `counter`, `s` or `left`, or any combination of them) counts how many times `counter[s[left]]` is greater than or equal `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`target += counter[s[left]] >= 0`

is equivalent to

`target = target + (1 if counter[s[left]] >= 0 else 0)`

and it's bad Python. Demand it be changed. Adding zero is stupid, and the whole thing is confusing.

```
if counter[s[left]] >= 0:
    target += 1
```

Comment: If you have a lot of these, especially in a row, the original version is more compact and probably more readable.

Comment: `if counter[s[left]] >= 0: target += 1` is also one line and more compact and more legible.